Heart Rate Monitor, replacing pulse sensor with ECG?
I'm completely new in this area, but I would like to try this project: https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/iot-heart-rate-monitor-project-using-arduino-and-esp8266
The only mismatch is that I have an ECG AD8232 instead of a sensor pulse, like they have.
Could you please give me a suggestion on how the circuit would look like with an ECG AD8232? Or, is this adjustment even possible?
Thank you!

try following one of the tutorials on the internet

I need to use specifically an ESP 8266 and to display the cardiogram using a web server, so this is a perfect match for me, Other projects I found on the internet need more adjustments in that sense.

How to redesign some whole project is a bit too big a topic for this site. But to begin with, have you read the datasheet, user guide and application notes published by AD regarding that IC?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In an ECG, the QRS complex signals the contraction of the ventricles, which sends blood into the aorta and then downstream, creating a pulse that can be felt or detected at various body points.  Thus, with few exceptions, every QRS complex in the ECG will result in a pulse beat.  Because of compliance in the vasculature, and other little bits of fluid mechanics, the pulse actually lags the QRS by a bit (In fact, it seems like the higher the blood pressure, the lower the lag), but I don't anticipate that this will be a problem.
So, the magic you are looking for is called "QRS Detection".  If you search on that, you'll find plenty of algorithms that do that.  It can be done in hardware or in software.  Here's a paper that does it in software (links to a pdf).
Then, the next step is to use QRS detection to generate approximately the same waveform as the "pulse sensor" would produce, and get that signal to the same pins as your project uses for the pulse sensor.  I have no idea what that pulse sensor outputs, but can't imagine it would be too difficult to figure out.
